# Alternative to pip

Tags: python, package-manager

The program pip drives me crazy.

Is there an alternative package manager for Python?

It has no proper dependency manager and installs packages twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python for scientific calculations / machine learning, you might as well adopt a distribution that installs all the packages packages you'll most commonly use at once.

Anaconda is a popular option  that comes with its own dependency manager ([conda](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda)). [Description page](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/). [Download page](http://continuum.io/downloads)

Includes NumPy, SciPy, Pandas, IPython, Matplotlib, Numba, Blaze, Bokeh and others.

There are [other Python distributions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDistributions) you can try, whatever fits your needs.

Comment: I am not using Python in  scientific calculations / machine learning. I want a general purpose package manager for packages in a virtual environment.

Comment: It also works on a virtual environment, they specifically advertise "great support for virtual environments". And they provide a stripped down version ([miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html)) that you can customize if you don't have much space on your virtual machine. I added a link to the direct downloads page in the main post.